# select all and some attribute from a table get different result in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've try to get result from sql query in codeigniter with mode select all attribute but it returns a PHP error but when I specify some attribute in give the right answer but the query is too long to be written.

This 2 mode select that I've try and give different result.

**First**

class model_kemiskinan extends CI_Model {

..... //constructor here

```
function get_kemiskinan_provinsi(){
    $this->tahun = "2011";
    $this->kodeProv = "31";        
    $this->query = "select * from kemiskinan where id_provinsi = ".$this->kodeProv." and tahun = ".$this->tahun;        
    $this->result = $this->db->query($this->query);                
    return $this->result->result();
}
```

Then the controlller pass it

```
public function testquery(){        
    $this->load->model('model_kemiskinan');                
    $data['hasil'] = $this->model_kemiskinan->get_kemiskinan_provinsi();        
    $data['main_content'] = 'test';        
    $this->load->view('template', $data);       
}
```

and the view 'test' respond it with these code:

```
if(is_array($hasil)){        
    foreach ($hasil as $baris ) {            
        echo $baris->tahun;
        echo $baris->id_provinsi;            
        echo "<br/>";
    }
```

And the result is this

```
A PHP Error was encountered 
Severity: Notice 
Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$tahun
```

**Second**

But if I change the select mode that look like this :

```
$this->query = "select tahun, id_provinsi from kemiskinan where id_provinsi = ".$this->kodeProv." and tahun = ".$this->tahun;
```

It will work properly

Is there any solution about select all mode?

-Thanks before-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like the documentation (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/examples.html) says:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT name, title, email FROM my_table');

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->title;
    echo $row->name;
    echo $row->email;
}

echo 'Total Results: ' . $query->num_rows();
```

you get only one row by calling result() so you need to call it by foreach:

```
function get_kemiskinan_provinsi(){
    $this->tahun = "2011";
    $this->kodeProv = "31";        
    $this->query = "select * from kemiskinan where id_provinsi = ".$this->kodeProv." and tahun = ".$this->tahun;        
    $this->result = $this->db->query($this->query); 

    $res = array();             
    foreach ($this->result->result() as $row)
    {
        $res[] = $row;
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Please recognize that the fields in the result object are case sensitive! If you have a field named "Tahun" in your db then "select tahun ..." will work in mysql and will give you an object where you can access $res->tahun.

If you do "select * ...." then you can only access it like this: $res->Tahun (with capial T)

Comment: after I try modify that parts, the same error still appear. 
what about my controller and view? -thanks before-

Comment: can you do a print_r($hasil); in your view please

Comment: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [No] => 55 [Id_provinsi] => 31 [Tahun] => 2011 [Jmlh_Pend_miskin1] => 363.42 [Jmlh_Pend_miskin2] => 0.00 [Jmlh_Pend_miskin3] => 363.42 [persentase_Pend_miskin1] => 3.75 [persentase_Pend_miskin2] => 0.00 [persentase_Pend_miskin3] => 3.75 [Garis_kemiskinan1] => 355480.00 [Garis_kemiskinan2] => 0.00 [Garis_kemiskinan3] => 355480.00 [IKP1_1] => 0.60 [IKP1_2] => 0.00 [IKP1_3] => 0.60 [IKP2_1] => 0.15 [IKP2_2] => 0.00 [IKP2_3] => 0.15 ) )